What's the translation of swiftboating in French?
From  Wikipedia:

Since the 2004 election, [swiftboating] has come to commonly refer to a political attack that is dishonest, personal, and unfair.[9][10]

What's the translation of swiftboating in French? Google Translate and Lingue didn't help.

I think you are not going to find translations for many words in current US politics or technology. Either because the word is too new, or the cultural context is entirely different, and the word didn't cross the Atlantic yet. So in many cases, we are going to use periphrases, or not even, if the context/concept is just non-existent in a French context.

Maybe lynchage politique winking at the well-known lynchage médiatique. I doubt the undertones are true to the original.

@FrançoisJurain Oui, mais on perd la notion d'attaque politique sur le passé militaire.

@Frank Est-ce que le swiftboating est toujours limité à ce type d'attaque ou est-ce que le champ d'utilisation s'est élargi depuis ? La citation de Wikipedia et certains exemples n'ont pas l'air de s'y restreindre. C'est un problème avec ce type de question où aucun attendu, aucun contexte d'utilisation n'est donné.

@jlliagre Pour exemple, on a entendu je crois swiftboating récemment dans une attaque de Vance sur Waltz, et spécifiquement, il s'agissait de mettre en question la carrière militaire (dans la réserve) de Waltz. On n'entend pas swiftboating pour une attaque politique en général par contre. Il me semble que c'est le seul contexte où le mot a refait surface récemment.

@jlliagre Quand j'ai vu la question de l'OP, j'ai immédiatement fait le rapprochement avec la controverse de cette semaine sur Vance/Waltz. J'ai pensé que c'est ce qui avait incité l'OP à soumettre cette question. Sinon, ce n'est pas un terme courant qu'on entend normalement.

Il n'y aurait apparemment pas de terme et des expressions sont utilisées.
La première de deux expressions qui ont été copiées ci-dessous est un essai de traduction de « swiftboating ».
attaque politique injuste ou fausse
attaque injuste et infondée
Des variantes sont possibles, comme par exemple les suivantes.

attaque (politique) infondée,  attaque (politique) mensongère, attaque (politique) injuste et mensongère

